# Are contracted pronunciations of mathematical functions common in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, ciencia, matemáticas

In mathematics, we have what are called hyperbolic trigonometric functions.  For example, hyperbolic sine, hyperbolic tangent, hyperbolic cosine, etc...  We generally write these functions with abbreviations like sinh, tanh, cosh, etc...  In English, we go one step further and abbreviate their pronunciation as well.  When we see 'sinh', we say "sinch".  When we see 'tanh', we also say 'tanch'.  When we see 'cosh', we also say 'cosh'.

I'm curious if something similar is practiced in Spanish as well.  Are these particular functions commonly pronounced in a contracted manner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say it is uncommon (at least in Spain) to abbreviate the pronunciation.

I've always heard the full pronunciation even though it's written in the contracted manner.

Comment: +1. I've never *heard* a contracted form of the hyperbolic functions (and I've taken courses making an extensive use of them)

Comment: I agree with @IgnacioContreras. I've never heard a contracted form, either. I've always heard "coseno hiperbólico", "tangente hiperbólica", etc.

Comment: I agree. The only "exception" I can think of right now could be sinc(x) function for "cardinal sine". In Spanish I have always called it "función sinc" instead of "función seno cardinal", indeed I have never heard anyone calling it by its original name.

Comment: @Javi: I've just learnt something. I had always read or heard "sinc", never "seno cardinal". And I've used it quite a lot!

Comment: Same here (Argentina)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not true.

In Spanish, we may write `sin(x)` or `sen(x)`, but in both cases we say "Seno de x":

- sin(x), sen(x): Seno de x
- cos(x): Coseno de x
- ...

We may also write `sinh(x)` or `senh(x)`, but we say "Seno hiperbólico de x"